# How to change password in active directory when password expired

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, ldap

In Microsoft Active Directory(AD), if someone password expired, how to change password **using their old password**.

I know `System.DirectoryService` has one `ChangePassword` Method, but it not working when the password expired.

I want some help, than you very much!

BTW, **cannot use `SetPassword`** Method, because it have to has special privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [NetUserChangePassword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa370650(v=vs.85).aspx) function in netapi32.dll.

```
[DllImport("netapi32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode,
    CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall,
    SetLastError=true )]
static extern uint NetUserChangePassword (
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string domainname,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string username,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string oldpassword,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string newpassword
);
```